ctrl + <del> or <backspace> won't delete a whole word in Neovim
problem: ctrl + <del> or ctrl + <backspace> doesn't delete a whole word. I know there's another way to do it in Neovim, but I want to change the current behaviour.
So I tried changing my mappings but ctrl + del doesn't work

I use powershell on the windows terminal to use neovim.
config in lua, highlighted lines are the changes I made


here's my current config GitHub

This is not really a programming issue, maybe it is better place your Neovim specific issue at: https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues

Yeah, you can map the key map like this.
vim.keymap.set("n", "<C-BS>", "dw", {silent = true, desc = 'delete from cursor to ending word'})
vim.keymap.set("n", "<C-Del>", "db", {silent = true, desc = 'delete from cursor to beginning word'})

But note that, in some case, <C-BS> does not work as expect.
